# what is difference between org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver and org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver?

Tags: hive

what is difference between org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver and org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver ?

Which one to use to Write a JDBC Client to connect to hive ?

Answer (score 3):

Hive 0.11 includes a new JDBC driver that works with HiveServer2, enabling users to write JDBC applications against Hive. The application needs to use the JDBC driver class and specify the network address and port in the connection URL in order to connect to Hive.
HiveServer2 (HIVE-2935), brings concurrency, authentication, and a foundation for authorization to Hive
HiveServer2 is an improved version of HiveServer that supports Kerberos authentication and multi-client concurrency and use the driver "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"

HiveServer1 or Thrift server  cannot handle concurrent requests from more than one client. This is actually a limitation imposed by the Thrift interface that HiveServer exports, and can't be resolved by modifying the HiveServer code.  The Driver which Hive Server "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"

Please find the links which will help you to understand more.
[org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveClient) and [org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients)

To work with, it depend on ur requirement which version you are having and how you have done Hive Configuration.