# Can Spring JdbcTemplate connect to hive?

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea, hive, spring-jdbc

I am developing a java web project which is based on spring. And I want to use Spring JdbcTemplate to connect to hive. But when I tested my service, it came out this error message

> "org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not
>   get JDBC Connection; nested exception is
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver
>   class 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDrive'".

The project is created by idea maven, but the hive jdbc driver is a local jar(it is located at WEB-INF/lib). So I am not sure whether the error is caused by the problem that my project still can't recognize the local jdbc driver jar or just because JdbcTemplate does not support hive connection. Can someone help me figure it out? thank you in advance.

Here are my code:

JdbcTemplate definition:

```
    <bean id="dataSourceTDW" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceTDW"/>
    </bean>
```

DAO class:

```
@Repository(value = "tdwQueryImp")
public class QueryDAOImp implements QueryDAO {
    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public List<Map<String,Object>> execute(String sql) {
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver? Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31957914/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by changing the class of datasource from `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` to `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource`.

Here are the beans configuration:

```
<bean id="hiveDriver" class="org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"/>

<bean id="dataSourceTDW" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource">
    <constructor-arg name="driver" ref="hiveDriver"/>
    <constructor-arg name="url" value="${url}"/>
    <constructor-arg name="username" value="${username}" />
    <constructor-arg name="password" value="${password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceTDW"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Kerberos Example:

```
@Component
public class HiveDataSource extends SimpleDriverDataSource {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HiveDataSource.class);

private final Subject subject;

@Autowired 
HiveDataSource(Subject subject, Driver hiveDriver, String jdbcUrl) {
    this.subject = subject;
    setUrl(jdbcUrl);
    setDriver(hiveDriver);
}

@Override
protected Connection getConnectionFromDriver(final Properties props) throws SQLException {

    try {
        return Subject.doAs(subject, (PrivilegedExceptionAction<Connection>)() -> getDriver().connect(getUrl(), props));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("Failed to get Hive JDBC connection.", e);
    }

    return null;

}
}
```

Here HiveDriver bean is defined as :

```
@Bean
HiveDriver hiveDriver() {
    HiveDriver impl = new HiveDriver() {
        @Override
        public Connection connect(String url, Properties info) throws SQLException {

            return acceptsURL(url) ? new HiveConnection(url, info) {
                @Override
                public void setAutoCommit(boolean autoCommit) throws SQLException {
                    /* do nothing */
                };

            } : null;
        }
    };
    return impl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can refer bellow link :

http://saurzcode.in/2015/01/connect-hiveserver2-service-jdbc-client/

and more

http://hadooptutorial.info/hive-jdbc-client-example/

https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/53629/writing-a-spring-boot-microservices-to-access-hive.html

Comment: Not in an answer. This post contains no information, only links, and links tend to break with time.